# How do you save image from canvas with button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a "save" button and I need it to allow the user to download the canvas image as a PNG or JPG file.

At the moment, I found this code:

```
$('#save').on("click",function(){
    var w=window.open('about:blank','image from canvas');
    w.document.write("<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL("image/png")+"' alt='from canvas'/>");
})
```

Which opens the canvas image into a new page, and allows the image to be downloaded (It shows the image as a black image otherwise). 
Is there a way in which when the user clicks the save button they download the image directly without clearing the current canvas or opening in a new page?

Comment: Maybe this [**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wboykinm/fL0q2uce/) will be of some use to you. This is using a anchor tag, not a button as it uses the `href` in the download function.

Comment: @NewToJS I copied the fiddle code to my file and it's working almost exactly the way I want! There's one thing though - My background is transparent and the code is giving me a completely black background behind the canvas image - is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `ctx.fillStyle` to `ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";` For example: [**JsFIddle Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/0qt8saoj/)

Comment: I found the code for replacing the background from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160098/change-html-canvas-black-background-to-white-background-when-creating-jpg-image
@NewToJS if you answer this question with what you wrote in your comment, I will pick it as the best answer. It helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

setting the `href` and than using `download` attribute is an easy trick for downloading canvas images, but it doesn't work always and in all browsers, I would recommend you use [FileSaver](https://fastcdn.org/FileSaver.js/1.1.20151003/FileSaver.min.js) for saving canvas images.

- Include the `FileSaver` either via CDN or locally as per your comfort.
- further in your code use `saveAs()` (this is defined in `FileSaver`) as follows:

code :

```
$('#save').on("click", function() {  
  canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {  
    saveAs(blob, 'output.png');  
  }, 'image/png');
});
```

this will work out fine.